# Why can't I use "Player.transform.position.y = maxY" in my Update function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that the player pos is equal to the maxY, if the player wants to go higher. But the code isn't valid, but in the if statement I can say it?

I tried it with a Vector 2, but it doesn't work because "player.transform.position.y is a float"

```
public float maxY;

void Start
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MyPlayer");
}

void Update()
{
    if (Player.transform.position.y >= maxY)
    {
        StartCoroutine("DontFlySoHigh");
        Player.transform.position.y = maxY;
    }
}
```

I want that the player can't go above `maxY`.
Or if you guys have a better idea to do a invisible border, just tell me.

Comment: It tells you in your console why you can't do `position.y = maxY`.  You can assign the whole vector3 but you cannot assign individual values, when it comes to `transform.position`.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-can-i-modify-transform-position-but-not-transform-position-y.504494/ Gives a good explanation as to why you cant do that when it comes to `transform.position`

Answer (score 4):

Because `position` is a `Vector3`, which is a `struct`, which is a value type, thus pass-by-value.

You cannot make changes to `[base].[any_struct].[component_of_struct]` because the struct you end up with after `[any_struct]` is a copy to the one assigned to `[base]`. Two, separate objects. Changing components of the copy will not be reflected back at the original, unless you assign the new `Vector3` to replace the original.

---

In this case, make your change like this:

```
var position = Player.transform.position;
position.y = maxY;
Player.transform.position = position;
```

---

You can further simplify this with an extension method:

```
public static class Vector3Extensions {
    public static Vector3 WithY(this Vector3 vector, float y) {
        vector.y = y;
        return vector;
    }
}
```

Then it becomes:

```
Player.transform.position = Player.transform.position.WithY(maxY);
```

Answer (score 0):

got it like this, thank you guys ;)

```
    void Update()
{
    if (Player.transform.position.y >= maxY)
    {
        //StartCoroutine("DontFlySoHigh");
        Player.transform.position = new Vector2(Player.transform.position.x, maxY);
    }
    if (Player.transform.position.x <= maxXleft)
    {
        Player.transform.position = new Vector2(maxXleft, Player.transform.position.y);
    }
    if (Player.transform.position.x >= maxXright)
    {
        Player.transform.position = new Vector2(maxXright, Player.transform.position.y);

    }
```

Comment: You can use `Mathf.Clamp` to limit left/right in a single operation instead of 2 IFs.

Comment: While this may technically solve the specific problem in the question, this answer would be better improved for future visitors if it included how/why it solves the problem in general.